# Held broken packages ROS-Indigo install on Ubuntu 14.04.5

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

After following the instructions on ROS Wiki,

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
```

Gives error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-indigo-perception but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-indigo-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I also tried

```
sudo apt-get install libsdformat1
```

And

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Nothing worked.
What to do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258320/held-broken-packages-ros-indigo-install-on-ubuntu-14.04.5/) by [jaskaranvirdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29882/jaskaranvirdi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-03-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-04-17**:
Please accept the answer if any of the below has helped you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure you have `main` enabled in your Ubuntu repositories.

---

Originally posted by [toblech](https://answers.ros.org/users/27825/toblech/) with karma: 86 on 2017-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic`, otherwise you may need to build from source.

---

Originally posted by [emef](https://answers.ros.org/users/29888/emef/) with karma: 41 on 2017-03-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you could try `apt-get update` if you haven't done already. You could also try unholding the packages if they are kept on hold by any chance. `apt-mark` ( with respective arguments )is a command that will enable you to do so.

---

Originally posted by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) with karma: 231 on 2017-04-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1